# Kilowatt Hour Definition

Tags: power, energy, watts

This is a very simple question but something that I'm not able to wrap my head around. [This Energy report](http://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.cfm?id=427&t=3) states generated electricity. But what does "generated  killowatthours" mean? I know that can't mean that the US produced that much electricity every hour...but what exactly does it mean?

Comment: If you produce one kilowatt for an hour, that's a "killowatt-hour". It's about 3.6 million joules, says Google.

Comment: "In 2011, the United States generated about 4,106 billion kilowatthours of electricity. "  in ONE year.

Comment: As there are about 8000 hours in a year, that means an average power generated of half a billion kilowatts, or 500GW. That suggests several hundred large (1-2GW) power stations - plausible.

Comment: @The Photon With the knowledge that a joule is a watt-second (`Ws`) you wouldn't need to ask Google to know that one kilowatt-hour is exactly 3600000 joule.

Comment: @starblue, totally right. Brain freeze on my part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing kilowatt hours with kilowatts *per* hour (which is a fairly useless measure of anything).

A kilowatt is a measure of the rate at which energy is delivered (also known as power). One kilowatt means that 1000 joules of energy is being delivered every second.

A kilowatt hour is a measure of total energy delivered.

```
kilowatt      = energy/time

kilowatt hour = kilowatt x time
              = (energy/time) x time
              = energy
```

So if your water heater draws 6 kilowatts when it is on, and is on for 30 minutes, then it has consumed 3 kilowatt hours.

According to the report:

> In 2011, the United States generated about 4,106 billion kilowatthours of electricity.  About 68% of the electricity generated was from fossil fuel (coal, natural gas, and petroleum), with 42% attributed from coal.

```
kilowatt hours = 4,106,000,000,000 kWh

hours          = 356.25 days * 24 hours/day
               = 8766 hours

kilowatts      = (kilowatt hours) / hours
               = 4,106,000,000,000 kWh / 8766 hours
               = 468,400,639 kW
```

So we can see that during 2011, if you were to measure the power being generated in the USA, it would be about half a Terawatt.

Comment: The ONE valid use I have seen for kilowatts per hour is for a factory making e.g. solar cells : if it makes one panel per hour, and it can generate 1kw, their output is 1kw/hour!