# amp hours measurement

Tags: power, amplifier

What is the best way to measure how many amp hours a device (in this case a resistive heater) is using? I have a resistive heater that is pulsed on and off periodically depending on ambient temperature. I can capture the waveform of the current over time with a scope. Do I just multiply the amount of current by the time every time it is turned on? Basically the waveform will look like a square wave.

Comment: Why would you measure amp hours if I may ask? Could you clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 1):

> I can capture the waveform of the current over time with a scope. Do I just multiply the amount of current by the time every time it is turned on?

Yes, that will work.

If (for instance) over a 2 hour period, you find the heater has been on, drawing 10A, for a total of 25% of the time, then you'll have used 5Ah in that time.

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need to measure the current consumption of the load in Amps. In that case, your instantaneous current for the heater when the pulse is at fully on, would be the current in Amps = (Supply Voltage/Resistance of the coil in ohms). Now if the PWM is on for 10% of the time and off for 90%, then your average current will be 10% of the fully on state. If it continues for 5 hours, you can say, your Amp Hour consumption is (10% * full on current * 5) Amp hours

Answer (score 0):

A Kill-a-Watt is a consumer device that plugs between the wall and the device you want to monitor. It will measure the current draw as well as keep track of the kW/h used by the device.

Comment: Kilowatt hours are not the same as kW/h.

Comment: I beg to differ. kWH or Kilowatt hours is defined as kilowatts of energy used per hour. My adding of the slash does not change the meaning. Either form is acceptable and interchangeable.

Comment: That's simply wrong. Kilowatt-hours is power used integrated over time. Kilowatts is a measure of power. It's equal to 1000 joules per second. Kilowatts per hour would measure the rate of change of power consumption or supply.

Comment: See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/61082/6334).

Answer (score 0):

Amp-hours (Ah) are rarely used other than for battery capacity comparison. They allow easy comparison when the units being compared are the same voltage.

Of much more use is the watt-hour (Wh) measurement which is a true measurement of energy and is independent of the voltage of the system.

For your application the simplest energy consumption estimation would be by measuring the 'on' current and the 'duty-cycle' or percentage on-time. For example,

- rating plate says 2000 W
- on time: 90 s
- off time: 110 s

then energy consumption in one hour will be \$ P \times duty\ cycle = 2000 \times \frac {90}{90 + 110} = 900 \ \mathrm {Wh} \$.